# How to read data of another module from the setting table?

Tags: opencart

In the controller of my module in `catalog/controller/module/my_module.php`, I'd like to read data of another module (such as affiliate or slideshow module) that is stored in the `setting` table.

In the controller, I have something like this:

```
class ControllerModuleMyModule extends Controller {
protected function index($setting) {
      ....
      ....
    }
}
```

where `$setting` gives me access to my current module's data from the setting table. Is there an easier way in Opencart (perhaps a built-in function) to access data of another module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's another modules data not yours that you want to access, the easiest way is to query the `setting` table for it unless you know exactly the key you want, in which case using

```
$this->config->get('module_name_setting_name');
```

For example, to get the featured product list of ID's, use

```
$ids = $this->config->get('featured_product');
```

which will provide you with a CSV of product ID's